# SQL Server: Curious about performance impact of this SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, select, common-table-expression

I have the following SQL statement:

```
WITH w1 AS (SELECT [Number] AS v1 FROM [MyTable] WHERE <condition>)
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN v1 < @Value THEN v1 ELSE @Value END)
FROM
  w1;
```

I'm just curious, say if MyTable contains 10 records matching to , how many times will the  statement be processed while performing the SQL statement above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will just get inlined and treated the same as if you had written

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [Number] < @Value THEN [Number] ELSE @Value END)
FROM [MyTable] 
WHERE <condition>
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, technically the [Number] part is not just that easy. Take a look at the whole SQL statement here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31368633/sql_query_001.txt

It is just a snapshot of what is being generated by an ASP NET script. So any idea if that can be optimized?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, execution plan will be to compute scalar for each row once, then aggregate. `w1` will be queried once for all matching values.

Comment: So you're saying it won't get executed twice per pass, right?

Comment: @ahmd0 No. CTE only defines a schema. Actual execution depends on the `select`. In the `select`, you only query it once.